Encountering issues with geopy inaccurately geocoding zip codes
I am developing a basic airport finder that reads traveler zip codes from an Excel spreadsheet, converts the zip codes into latitude and longitude coordinates, and matches these coordinates with a list of the closest 30 major US airports and their respective coordinates provided in the code. However, Geopy is converting traveler zip codes into coordinates that are not accurately reflecting the proximity to the expected closest airports.
`import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim, GoogleV3
from geopy.distance import geodesic

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="***************************")

major_airports = {
    'JFK International Airport': (59.3407345, 18.0511125),  # New York, USA
    'LAX International Airport': (38.1608630571429, 13.0996827047619), # Los Angeles, USA
    'O\'Hare International Airport': (43.64324975, 13.3061823891233), # Chicago, USA
    'San Francisco Bay Oakland International Airport': (58.2350709457143, 22.6524254714286), #     San Francisco, USA
    'Orlando International Airport': (26.64315653, 49.96198901), # Orlando, USA
    'Miami International Airport': (25.8132240548428, -80.2337842997653), # Miami, USA
    'Hartsfield–Jackson Atlanta International Airport': (43.88072255, 4.46909519811753), # Atlanta,   USA
    'Baltimore/Washington International Thurgood Marshall Airport': (47.3388705,     5.00092058238689), # Baltimore, USA
    'Washington Dulles International Airport': (41.8246441, 8.81611469485657), # Dulles, USA
    'Newark Liberty International Airport': (-36.085358645, -57.7898771), # Newark, USA
    'John Glenn Columbus International Airport': (40.0178767194908, -82.9263765965759), # Colombus, USA
    'Cleveland Hopkins International Airport': (51.51389575, 7.47750533260667), # Cleveland, USA
    'Pittsburg International Airport': (59.1963309345865, 17.6465945977444), # Pittsburg, USA
    'Dallas Fort Worth International Airport': (-0.826647027272727, 117.2461445), # Dallas, USA
    'George Bush Intercontinental Airport': (49.399349, 24.440886), # Houston, USA
    'Phoenix Sky Harbor International Airport': (33.436887161194, -112.022041685753), # Phoenix, USA
    'San Diego International Airport': (48.5913332802129, 17.8272011688263), # San Diego, USA
    'Denver International Airport': (43.8466357123711, 17.184626832646), # Denver, USA
    'Tampa International Airport': (28.0107725020464, -82.5062709376535), # Tampa, USA
    'Louis Armstrong New Orleans International Airport': (29.9922118212769, -90.2497090879911), # New Orleans, USA
    'Charlotte Douglas International Airport': (35.2313816216061, -80.8981937532505), # Charlotte, USA
    'Harry Reid International Airport': (56.3079127071428, 22.3385901071429), # Las Vegas, USA
    'Birmingham-Shuttlesworth International Airport': (28.0084775, -15.3748895), # Birmingham, USA
    'Detroit Metropolitan Wayne County Airport': (49.2556783423529, 25.6976986847059), # Detroit, USA
    'Milwaukee Mitchell International Airport': (47.579379825, 34.4115374875), # Milwaukee, USA
    'Nashville International Airport': (51.33591575, 9.90967109277852), # Nashville, USA
    'Charleston International Airport': (32.8950217078947, -80.0664747684211), # Charleston, USA
    'Raleigh-Durham International Airport': (49.23916285, 0.502013223194076), # Raleigh Durham, USA
    # Add more major airports with their coordinates here
}

def geocode_zip_code(zip_code):
    """Geocode a zip code and return the coordinates (latitude, longitude)."""
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(zip_code)
        if location:
        return location.latitude, location.longitude
    else:
        print(f"Geocoding failed for zip code: {zip_code}")
        return None, None
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error occurred while geocoding zip code: {zip_code}. Error: {e}")
    return None, None

def find_closest_airport(zip_coords, airports):
"""Find the closest airport to the given zip code coordinates."""
closest_airport = None
min_distance = float('inf')
for airport, coords in airports.items():
    # Calculate the distance between zip_coords and the airport's coordinates
    distance = geodesic(zip_coords, coords).miles
    
    # Update the closest airport if the current distance is less than the minimum distance
    if distance < min_distance:
        min_distance = distance
        closest_airport = airport

return closest_airport

def main(file_path):
    # Load the Excel spreadsheet
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

    # Add a new column for the closest major airport
    df['Closest Major Airport'] = ''

    # Process each person's zip code
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
    zip_code = row['zip_code']
    
    # Geocode the zip code
    zip_coords = geocode_zip_code(zip_code)
    
    if zip_coords != (None, None):
        # Find the closest major airport to the given zip code coordinates
        closest_airport = find_closest_airport(zip_coords, major_airports)
        
        # Store the closest airport in the DataFrame
        df.loc[index, 'Closest Major Airport'] = closest_airport
    else:
        # If geocoding fails, mark the entry as 'Unknown'
        df.loc[index, 'Closest Major Airport'] = 'Unknown'

    df.to_excel(file_path, index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Specify the path of the Excel file
    file_path = "input_and_output.xlsx"

    # Run the main function
    main(file_path)

